# Socket.io emit progress check

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I use Socket.io for uploading files. It works fine with the following schema:

1. Client: read file from input and encode it to Base64 and compress it
2. **Client: Emit a Socket.io event "upload" including compressed file as a piece of data**
3. Server: Listen to "upload" event, uncompress and decode file and save it

The problem occurs for large files: **I cannot see a progress of data sent via client emit** (like I do with XHR).

To solve these problems I have to track (check) upload progress of emit event. How can I do this?

---

***I would like to listen to upload progress on CLIENT SIDE ONLY***

---

Thanks to bnuhero, socketio-file-upload gives a possibility to listen to progress on server side and emit messages to client side when let's say every 5% or 20% is uploaded. So it means to send 20 or 5 messages respectively per file. I would like to listen to progress on client side.

---

Looks like there is no possibility to check the progress on client side with naked Socket.io. Io-stream solves that problem.

Comment: Do you want to upload files from a browser to a Node.js server that runs Socket.io? [socketio-file-upload](https://npmjs.org/package/socketio-file-upload) may be a good choice. It provides a server-side event called progress.

Comment: Determine the size, cut it in pieces, emit some event like "data" and when all pieces are sent, emit an "end" event, mirror that locig on the server, and you can now upload any size of data you'd like

Comment: Oh and if the mehtod you use to compress supports events or streams, you can even pipe those streams directly to the socket events, essentially streaming your file instead of buffering it at both sides

Comment: bnuhero, thanks. I edited a question. I would like an event on client side like for XHR.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

client:

```
var chunk_size = 100;
var compressed_data = 'some-long-string';
var reg = new RegExp('/.{1,'+chunk_size+'}/g');
var parts = compressed_data .match(reg);
var l = parts.length -1;

client.socket.emit('data', parts.pop());

client.socket.on('received', function () {
    client.socket.emit('data', [l - parts.lengt, parts.pop()]);
});
```

server:

```
sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  var parts = [];

  socket.on('data', function (data) {
     if (data[1] === undefined) {
         fs.writeFile(parts.join(''), callback...);
     } else {
         parts[data[0]] = data[1];
         socket.emit('received');
     }
  });


});
```

if this still doesnt work, you could add a negotiation between the server and client
the server responsing with an "received" event and the client sending the next chunk on receiving the "recieved" event

that allows your server to throttle the speed of the client, this however should allready be working through the socket library you use

### EDIT:

included feedback and message order

### EDIT2:

I think i misunderstood your question

but to solve the issue as i understand it now, eg having a indication on when the buffer is flushed for each part it flushes there are 2 options, either have it still simulate that behavior, or accept the chunks the server accepts and use that as the size of each part.

The latter is the actual progress so il give an example of that (if the server accepts chunks of 1Mb and the file is 1Mb it will still go from 0 to 100 in one step tho.

https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-stream

the server example is just what is shown on that github page

the client:

```
var io = require('socket.io-client');
var ss = require('socket.io-stream');

var socket = io.connect('http://example.com/user');
var stream = ss.createStream();
var filename = 'profile.jpg';
var through = require('through');

var compressed_data = 'some-long-string';
var l = compressed_data .length;
var total_progress = 0;

//pass the stream trough throug, giving feedback for each chunk passed
var tr = through(function (chunk) {
    total_progress += chunk.toString().length;
    client.socket.emit('progress', l, total_progress);
    this.queue(chunk)
}, function () {
    client.socket.emit('progress', l, l);
})

//use the streaming version of socket.io
ss(socket).emit('profile-image', stream, {name: filename});

//get a stream for the compressed_data
//filter it trough tr for the progress indication
//and pass it to the socket stream
fs.createReadStream(compressed_data ).pipe(tr).pipe(stream);
```

streams have a backoff mechanism, the server accepts each chunk of the stream buffer
if the server slows down the stream is read at a lower rate, giving you more progress inciations

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In your code emitted events from foreach part can be received by server in wrong order, so I need to check the order. Moreover I need to check if all parts of chunks received. Also I do not see a part, where it actually checks the progress. I have edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Thank you. This partly solves the problem. However, lets imagine it is crucial for the application to track each 0.1% of upload progress. This means 2000 emits (1000 from client and 1000 from server). Not elegant. I appreciate that your solution allows to retry (if "parts" var is always available) upload if it was interrupted, but this is not a problem I am trying to solve.

Comment: @igorpavlov since your client is another node app, you should relly use streams for sending files the process.stdin is a sream, and there is a streaming module for compression also, and most likely one for b64 encoding. Use those, otherwise you will slow your client and possibly your server down a lot

Comment: I never told that my client is a node app.

Comment: I know, but then the initial comment you received solves your question

Comment: https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-stream#browser the io-stream is also available on the browser tho, so it should work either case

Comment: I will stick with io-stream then. Thanks!

Comment: @PaulScheltema I'm using socket.io-stream in the client like you, and (since this is node-like programming), making a build via browserify, however, when I'm doing an attemp to use socket-stream it throws me an error : Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './_stream_duplex' , did you have a problem like this ? any help ?

Comment: @alexserver hi, for what i can see from the minified code, it tries to register the libraries it references trough an amd or mnodule.exports and the like, at the end of the file the registerd modules are listed, i'm guessing something goes wrong with the registering. Also the current version of the file is a month old, which is newer than the one i used, maby the maintainer of the repo can help you out there.

Comment: @PaulScheltema I finally found the solution: upgrade the browserify. It seems that the old version of browserify had this problems finding the references that you said. Thanks.

Comment: @igorpavlov Just to clarify, you know that WebSockets are based on the TCP protocol, which by definition maintains the order of data? So if you call `emit` three times with `3`, `5` and `9`, you will get those values in the same order on the server, no need to send indices like with UDP or AJAX (even if WS are not available, Socket.IO fallbacks to long-polling, which behaves just like TCP).